# Load hbm.xml files from different jars in webapp

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have an application which uses 2 different DAO modules(from Different JAR files) which point to same database.
Since i can't use muliple dataSources here, i can't create multiple sessionFactories.
I need to load hbm.xml files from these modules for my single sessionFactory.

When i try to use:

```
<util:list id="mappingLocations">
    <value>classpath*:**/*.hbm.xml</value>
</util:list>
```

i get:

```
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.InvalidMappingException: Could not parse mapping document from input stream
```

exception.

Could you point me in the right direction to get this working.
I am using XML config.

```
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:namingStrategy-ref="namingStrategy"
    p:hibernateProperties-ref="hibernateProperties">
    <property name="mappingLocations">
        <value>classpath*:**/*.hbm.xml</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

I have also tried `<value> inside <list>`

Comment: Don't use `util:list` just put `classpath*:**/*.hbm.xml` as value for the property `mappingLocations` in your session factory.

Comment: Different modules from different JAR files.

Comment: Doesn't matter...

Comment: yes @M.Deinum mentioned classpath*: will scan all the jars available in your classpath. Just put classpath*:**/*.hbm.xml for 'mappingLocation'

Comment: @kuhajeyan Tried it. but still getting the same exception.

Comment: can you update what you have tried

Comment: @kuhajeyan updated question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had hbm with same name in both the packages.
Once i removed the hbm from one package (which was mistakenly placed there) the issue got resolved.